# What does * mean in java's main args list?

Tags: java

I wrote a class like this and named it `Solution.java`.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args.length);
    }
}
```

BUt when I run it in Terminal, I got a result like this:

```
>  /Users/WangWei  java Solution *
18
>  /Users/WangWei
```

Why 18?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's probably the number of files in your working directory.

The result of `*` is not specific to Java. It is specific to the environment you are working in, i.e. the working directory and the kind of shell (Windows command prompt, bash, ...) you are using to run the java command. This is because the shell processes and evaluates the command line before starting the process. It replaces the `*`.

To preserve a `*` as a command line argument, you need to quote it:

```
java Solution '*'
```

Comment: __NOT double quotes__; use _single quotes_ in order to prevent interpretation by the shell.

Comment: Even on *nix platforms, one ought to use single-quotes in order to prevent characters being interpreted by the shell.  Try saying `echo "$HOME"` and `echo '$HOME'` to figure the difference.

Comment: Changed quoting as suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Your shell is interpreting the contents of the current folder - there are 18 files being passed in. Use singles quotes to avoid interpreting the asterisk

```
java Solution '*'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add this to your code and you'll see:

```
for(String line: args)
  System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 3):

The number of files in your directory.

18 shows that 18 files are there in your directory.